# Creating BigInsights (IBM Hadoop) Docker image, sysctl issue

Tags: hadoop, docker, ibm-cloud, sysctl, biginsights

I'm trying to create a docker image using IBM BigInsights QuickStart Edition to be run on a DOCKER container cloud (e.g. IBM Bluemix) with the Native Software Installer which can be found here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/biginsights/quick-start/downloads.html

The problem is that during installation I get errors that some kernel parameters accessible using sysctl are not set correctly.

If I adjust them using the Dockerfile I get an error saying:

Read-Only filesystem

Now I'm wondering if it is possible to create a BigInsights Image at all since the kernel parameters have to be set on the host machine which of course I cannot control in a container cloud.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM centos:latest

COPY biginsights-3.0.0.2-quickstart-nonproduction-Linux-amd64-b20150120_1502 /usr/local/biginsights-3.0.0.2-quickstart-nonproduction-Linux-amd64-b20150120_1502

RUN yum -y install tar
RUN yum -y install hostname
RUN yum -y install expect
RUN yum -y install net-tools
RUN yum -y install openssh
RUN yum -y install openssh-clients
RUN yum -y install openssh-server
RUN yum -y install passwd
RUN yum -y install sudo


RUN ssh-keygen -f id_rsa -t rsa -N ''

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh
RUN mv id_rsa* /root/.ssh/
RUN cat /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
RUN cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config |sed 's/#PubkeyAuthentication yes/PubkeyAuthentication yes/' | sed 's/#RSAAuthentication yes/RSAAuthentication yes/'| sed 's/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_rsa_key/'| sed 's/HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ecdsa_key/#HostKey \/etc\/ssh\/ssh_host_ecdsa_key/' > /etc/ssh/sshd_config.stage
RUN mv /etc/ssh/sshd_config.stage /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key -N '' -t rsa1
RUN ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key -N '' -t rsa
RUN ssh-keygen -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key -N '' -t dsa
RUN ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key -N ''
```

And after attaching to the container I run the following commands:

```
/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config
cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub  |awk '{print "localhost " $1" "$2}' > /root/.ssh/known_hosts


echo "UUID=dummy /dummy    dummy   defaults,noauto 0 0" >> /etc/fstab

export myip=`ifconfig |grep netmask|head -1|awk '{print $2}'`
export myhostname=`hostname`

cat /usr/local/biginsights-3.0.0.2-quickstart-nonproduction-Linux-amd64-b20150120_1502/silent-install/sample-install-enterprise-defaultFlat.xml |sed 's/9.125.91.82/'"$myip"'/g' |sed 's/node.sample.ibm.com/'"$myhostname"'/g' |sed 's/<partitions>1<\/partitions>/<partitions>2<\/partitions>/' > /usr/local/biginsights-3.0.0.2-quickstart-nonproduction-Linux-amd64-b20150120_1502/install.xml

/usr/local/biginsights-3.0.0.2-quickstart-nonproduction-Linux-amd64-b20150120_1502/silent-install/silent-install.sh
```

The exact error is:

```
[ERROR] (CDYIN0220E) 172.17.0.49: The kernel parameter kernel.pid_max is not set to 4194303.  Use the sysctl program to set the kernel.pid_max parameter to 4194303.
[ERROR] (CDYIN0221E) 172.17.0.49: The kernel parameter net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range is not set to a minimum of 1024.  Use the sysctl program to set the minimum to 1024.
[ERROR] (CDYIN0222E) 172.17.0.49: The kernel parameter net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range is not set to a maximum of 64000.  Use the sysctl program to set the maximum to 64000 or greater.
```

So basically how can SW be dockerized requiring changes like kernel parameters to be set?

best regards

Romeo (Kienzler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running the commands with `sudo`